# Equality comparison in an if statement in R

Tags: r

I have a list of data.frames:

```
book=list(ask,bid)
```

and I want to iterate through each data.frame like so:

```
book.total_volumes <- function(book) {
  
  bid_total_volume=0
  ask_total_volume=0
  
  for(book in book) {
    if(book=="bid"){
    for(value in book[,"volumes"]) { 
      bid_total_volume=bid_total_volume+value }
    }
  
  if(book=="ask"){
    for(value in book[,"volumes"]) { 
      ask_total_volume=ask_total_volume+value }
  }
  }
  
  print(bid_total_volume)
  print(ask_total_volume)
  
}



book.total_volumes(book)
```

when doing the if statement, how can I check if the current book name is equals to "bid" or if it is equals to "ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the elements of you list book aren't named. Another issue is that I don't think you can define `book in book` in a loop, this will overwrite the first book variable...

Here is the quick answer using  `lapply` function. It apply the same function to all elements of a list and return the values in the same order.

```
ask = data.frame(title = c("hello", "book"),
                 volumes = c(1, 42))
bid = data.frame(title = c("hello", "book"),
                 volumes = c(12, 1))
book=list(ask,bid)

print(unlist(lapply(book, function(x) sum(x[,"volumes"]))))
```

A longer version of this could be below. Note that list in R are also ordered.

```
book.total_volumes <- function(book) {
  res <- c(ask = 0, bid = 0)
  
  for(i in 1:length(book)){
    res[i] = sum(book[[i]][, "volumes"])
    # You can replace sum with a loop but it's good practice in R to vectorise code.
  }
  print(res)
}
book.total_volumes(book)
```

If you name the elements of you list, this code will work but this is not very optimal as functions exist to do this in less code.

```
book=list(ask = ask, bid = bid)

book.total_volumes <- function(book) {
  
  bid_total_volume=0
  ask_total_volume=0
  
  for(i in seq_along(book)) {
    if(names(book)[i] == "bid"){
      for(value in book[[i]][,"volumes"]) {
        bid_total_volume = bid_total_volume + value 
      }
    }
    
    if(names(book)[i]=="ask"){
      for(value in book[[i]][,"volumes"]) {
        ask_total_volume  =ask_total_volume + value
      }
    }
  }
  
  print(bid_total_volume)
  print(ask_total_volume)
  
}

book.total_volumes(book)
```